# mediaRecorder.prepare(); IOEXCEPTION error

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Actually I am trying to record voice call using mediarecorder. My code is working for some devices but like lenovo sony it's not working. It's giving `IOEXCEPTION` error when `mediarecorder.prepare()` is called. This is my code

```
{
  cou = 1;
  String nam = "/"+name+"("+cou+")"+".wav";
  String voicefile = recordfolder + nam ;
  File vf = new File(voicefile);
  while (vf.exists()) {
    cou = cou + 1;
    nam = "/"+name+"("+cou+")"+".wav";
    voicefile = recordfolder + nam ;
    vf = new File(voicefile);
    System.out.println("cou valuee"+cou);
  }
  System.out.println("cou value isssssss" + cou);
  voicefile = recordfolder + nam ;
  try {
    mymediarecorder();
  }
  catch (Exception e {
    System.out.println("error to run mediarecorder function");
  }
  try {
    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(voicefile);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    System.out.println("audio file setup done");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("now problem hereee");
  }
  try {
    myAudioRecorder.prepare();
  }
  catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    System.out.println("problem to prepare .wav");
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("problem to prepare .wav IOEXCEPTION ");
  }
  myAudioRecorder.start();
}
```

Comment: i have found the solution for this....it was very simple it should be .amr file and main problem is in this line myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL); it will be  myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);